# Meaning of ‘draw out’

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I’m translating an English novel into Italian but I’m stuck on the meaning of one sentence and I was wondering if you could help me:

> Why—his voice **seemed to draw out soft and subtle**, it penetrated her nerves—why, what do you think it is?

Comment: Could you give some more context, i.e., the sentences surrounding this sentence? There are several ways I can think of interpreting _draw out_, but it’s impossible to tell which is the correct one without knowing what the greater context is. It definitely has to do with the way his voice comes out of him, how it sounds—but a more detailed description requires the whole scenario.

Comment: In that context, it means "*come out [out his mouth], taking its own sweet time*". In general, to "*draw out*" either means to "[*protract*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protract) / *prolong*" or  "[*elicit*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elicit)". In your quote, it's that his speech is protracted (for the meaning of "induce to emerge" to apply here, the verb would have to have been used transitively, but in your quote it's used intransitively).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think the actual quote is: **"His voice seemed to draw out soft and subtle, it penetrated her nerves"** I'd say [prolongare](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/prolungare) = *draw out* and *dolcemente* = soft and gentle

Comment: Note the confusion / whatever with **drawn out** (with an "n")

Answer (score 1):

To *draw out* here means to elongate.  It's typically used non-reflexively, as in "drawn-out goodbye" and "to draw out limited supplies".

Here it is used in a reflexive sense, the voice draws itself out, the words are spoken slowly and with pauses between them, so his manner seems languid and indifferent.

The Italian equivalent might be *strascicare*, to drag or scuff.

Answer (score 0):

"Draw out" here just means "come out" or "flow out", you could translate with "fluire" or even "esalare" (exhale) and similar.

On Wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draw) you can see the meaning

> To take into the lungs; to inhale.

All such senses are related to the etymological meaning, "pull": in this context you could also say blow.

Answer (score -4):

In a word, you can't use "draw out" intransitively.  it's half a phrase; it should be "draw out noun."

---

Personally... since "draw out" means, uh, "draw out"

(as in say "draw out a piece of string" ... so, it means basically "pull out")

I would personally be inclined to only use it in that way.

So for example:

> his voice seemed to draw out beauty, it penetrated all her lips ..

or whatever

For me personally "his voice seemed to draw out soft and subtle" simply makes so sense.

After the "draw out" I'm looking for .. **what did it draw out**?  string? beauty? mystery? body fluids?

(For me, poetry that is just "pretty phrases" ("poetic" phrases) is weak poetry. For me, poetry is ingeniously stating reality, not merely "using poetic words".  So for example, from Shakespeare, "as in my salad days, when I was green in judgment, cold in blood." Note that the words have incredible striking meaning which make you think deeply, but they're just ordinary words, not "poetic sounding" words or phrases.)

Again, quite simply, "draw out" means "draw out" so, in a word, you need something after it .. draw out love, draw out my heart ... whatever you actually **mean**.

If it was a lame-ass creative writing class, here I'd say "well WHAT, SPECIFICALLY is he drawing out that is so amazing it makes her pee her pants?  WHAT is he drawing out?"

Comment: Hey B-ster.  sure, that was an example from shakespeare, i clarified the sentence dude.  good one

Comment: I  meant _you_ write some poetry following that prnciple

Comment: Well i did, it's in the quoted area on the fifth line.

Comment: @JoeBlow "Draw out *what*"? *His voice*.

Comment: Dan - that makes zero sense.  the sentence states **his voice is** drawing out something, dude.  What is it drawing out?  What is **his voice** drawing out?  Answers might include tension, time itself, sex, beauty, the very air of hades .. and so on.

Comment: No, bud, his *voice drew out of his body*, *as if* someone were pulling it soft and slow, like a silken ribbon (or an elastic band streeeetching). It's simile. It makes perfect sense (which is why no one else is questioning it).

Comment: Dan - you mean, similar to the phrases "his voice seemed to drag on" or "his voiced seemed to really grate" or "his voice seemed to boom loudly.." .. right?  For me "draw out _ _" can only be followed by a noun (e.g., "draw out silk")  For the sense you mean, for me it would be more like "his voice seems to draw itself out ..". or indeed "his voice was drawn out of his body".  Anyways - it's no big deal right.  back to work!

Comment: @Joe Blow: This is clearly an ***intransitive*** use of the phrasal verb *"draw out"*. You can say *"his voice seemed to tremble"*, and you wouldn't ask *"tremble what"*? The OED has one intransitive definition of *"draw out"* that seems to fit: *"to extend in length; to become longer"*.  And that's what I think it means here.

Comment: Hi Peter; for me "draw out" isn't intransitive. In your example, it would be like: "His voice seemed to tremble the."  I would be saying "what the fuck did it tremble, that makes no sense? it should be 'tremble the stars' or whatever."  Anyways, I totally understand what you mean and it's awesome you bothered to check the OED!  So let's leave it at that.

Comment: To be clear, I'm saying ...... "You guys are all wrong, but let's leave it at that."  :-)

Comment: (Again as I mentioned above, "drawn out" can and should be used as the writer tried to use "draw out".  indeed for me the passage is nothing more than a typo. it should be "voice seemed to be drawn out, soft and subtle..."  TBC that's what you guys are asserting it means, right.  i.e. for you "voice seemed to draw out" == "voice seemed to be drawn out" )

Comment: bobie - D.H.Lawrence - that sucker would have some ridiculously long french passage, and start going on about the solar plexus right

Comment: @joeblow For *me* green means red and up means down. Good thing we have dictionaries, so we know what words mean for everyone else, eh?

Comment: @Joe Blow: Since Lawrence's sentence only makes sense if *draw out* is used intransitively, and the OED says that it can be used intransitively, I think it's pretty clear that he is using it intransitively, even if this use isn't part of your dialect of English. If he used the word *puttees*, and you didn't know it, I assume you wouldn't insist he was making the word up, but would instead look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: Hey Peter!  *"Since Lawrence's sentence only makes sense if draw out is used intransitively"* right, that's why it makes no sense.  ;-)  "the OED says that it can be used intransitively" they're wrong, it's silly. the OED is often totally wrong. this is a good example!  :) the OED means less than nothing. **the OED is an astounding source of *reference***, so, it probably includes excellent examples of draw out used the wrong way, as in the example here. but regarding "what is common" or "what sounds right" language is just an opinion. BY ALL MEANS u can disagree w/ me on this one!

Comment: Actually, looking on Google, it seems that the only thing that commonly *"draws out"* in the intransitive sense are units of time;  more specifically, *the days are drawing out"* is relatively commonly used, and it means that they're getting longer (*days* are in the OED's citation). And there are a few related usages. But I can't find anything similar to Lawrence's usage.